# How can I create multithread for a for loop?

Tags: java, multithreading

**Code snippet**

```
 @Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MonitoringItems {

String servers = prop.getProperty("SERVERS");   
String[] serverArray = servers.split("@!");

List<DartModel> data = new ArrayList<DartModel>();
for(String server:serverArray) {    

try {

    conn = new ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection(server);
    conn.connect();
    boolean isAuthenticated = conn
            .authenticateWithPassword(username_array[j],
                    password_array[j]);
    if (isAuthenticated == false) {
        throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");
    }
```

I have a array called serverArray that contains a list of 200 different servers. This loop  loops through 200 different servers. How can I create a thread for each server that way they all can run simultaneously. The order of how it prints out is not a big deal for me. Each thread should run 1 server, should not run the same server.

I've done some simple multithreading tutorials but all it do is printing the same stuff with a different ID to show which thread is printing.

Comment: If you wrap each part in a future you could probably achieve what you want.

Comment: and take a look at something like Thread factory....

Comment: @Carcigenicate can you give me a generic example?

Comment: @Jackie I'm on my phone, so that would be difficult. Basically you give it a function that you want to parallellize, it it will potentially run in in parallel on a separate thread. Just make body of the loop a function, and give it to a a future. Note that unless you have 200 processing cores in your computer, you'll never be able to run all at once.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Currently my application runs, but it takes over 3-5 minutes for it to finish compiling. Then it takes another 3-5 minutes when I open up localhost:8080 to display the data into a webpage. Whats the maximum I can run using future?

Comment: @Jackie Multithreading can't reduce compile time. It may actually increase it by adding a little complexity. And are you saying it takes 3-5 minutes to load a single page, once?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, it currently take 3-5 to load a single page once. Because each server is being authenticated once every loop and it is getting data from it. It takes 1-2 seconds to printout one server with it's details X 200 times.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Java 8, you can use the streams to achieve a multithreaded loop:

```
serverArray.parallelStream().forEach(server -> {
    try {
        ...
    }});
```

Make sure that everything touched inside the loop is Thread-Safe.
This works for `Collections`, for `Arrays` you can use the static converter :

`Arrays.stream(serverArray).parallel()`

---

*More informations about Lamba expressions:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html*

*More informations about parallel streams:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html*

Comment: That looks promising on what I have to do. Can you elaborate a little more on that? It's my first time seeing such code.

Comment: I don't really know what to elaborate. I added two links to the official documentation about Lamba expressions and parallel streams. Hope this help! Tell me if you have precise questions.